# How to Show a Page if Application is Launched for the First Time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am wondering how to signal whether an appication is launched for the very first time, or has already been launched before. The reason I want to do this is to show a very short informative message before the application is ever used, while every other time the application is launched nothing shows. Would I place something in App.xaml.cs like the following

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if (!settings.Contains("WasLaunched")) 
{
  MessageBox.Show("First time to launch");
  settings.Add("WasLaunched", true);
}
```

And if `(!settings.Contains("WasLaunched")` navigate to the 'first launch page' as opposed to the 'main page'? Can someone point me to any good references on this implementation?

EDIT**

I changed my `WMAppManifest.xml` default page to `LaunchPage.xaml`

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="LaunchPage.xaml" />
```

And created my UriMapper class

```
public class LoginUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri.OriginalString == "/LaunchPage.xaml")
        {
            if (Settings.FirstLoad.Value == true)
            {
                //Navigate to Welcome Page with quick first time user info
                uri = new Uri("/Views/WelcomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else
            {
                ///Navigate to the actual Main Page
                uri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
        }
        return uri;
    }
}
```

But how do I change App.xaml.cs accordingly

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    //how to check and navigate to correct page for this specific method?
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    //how to check and navigate to correct page for this specific method?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd better to use the power of [UriMapper](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/01/12/urimapper-in-windows-phone.aspx)

[Here you can find a good article](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/06/18/Using-a-custom-UriMapper-to-navigate-to-a-login-screen.aspx).

The core idea is:

You should define an empty page (`EntryPage.xaml`) and set it as a default page of your app.
Then in your custom `UriMapper` you overload the `MapUri` method.

```
   public class YourUriMapper : UriMapperBase
   {
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri.OriginalString == "/EntryPage.xaml")
        {
            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

            if (!settings.Contains("WasLaunched"))
            {
                 uri = new Uri("/FirstRunInfoPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else
            {
                 uri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
             }
         }
            return uri;
     } 
  }
```

Then on app initialization you should define which `UriMapper` to use:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    RootFrame.UriMapper = new YourUriMapper();
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved == false)
    {
      // tombstoned! Need to restore state
      RootFrame.UriMapper = new YourUriMapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I followed your advice and edited my initial question above. I am just now unsure in `App.xaml.cs` of how to determine which page to navigate to based on whether the application is loading for its first time or regularly?

Comment: Worked great! I've noticed though that after hitting the WelcomePage and then navigating to the actual MainPage, the WelcomePage still exists in the back stack. Would I just check this on the OnNavigatedTo event in MainPage and then remove the page from the back stack accordingly? What do you suggest as the best method in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241529/clearing-backstack-in-navigationservice

Answer (score 3):

The best approach for the check is to write the status in the Isolated storage as you currently are. To redirect to the appropriate page, I would personally use a URI mapper. that way, your first intended entry page would be in the navigation first entry stack, preventing users from navigating back to the first page. A typical use case would be to redirect a user to a an authentication page when a user isn't authenticated and to a home page when the user is already authenticated, see [This example](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/06/18/Using-a-custom-UriMapper-to-navigate-to-a-login-screen.aspx)

```
  public App()
    {
        SetUpLandingPageView();
    }


     void SetUpLandingPageView()
    {
        var isLaunched = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("WasLaunched");

        // Get the UriMapper from the app.xaml resources, and assign it to the root frame
        var mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;

        if (mapper == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Mapper must be configured");

        RootFrame.UriMapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;

        // Update the mapper as appropriate
        mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = isLaunched ? new Uri("/Views/HomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative) : new Uri("/Views/Introduction.xaml", UriKind.Relative);    
    }
```

In the app.xaml

Namespace:

```
xmlns:UriMapper="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

Xaml

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <UriMapper:UriMapper x:Name="mapper">
            <UriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/MainPage.xaml" />
        </UriMapper:UriMapper>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```